# Invoking static opencv library

Tags: c++, opencv

I have built a static opencv library based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222248/building-opencv-as-static-libraries), and after that I want to invoke the static opencv library for my application. However, it seems that the application program cannot link the static opencv library, and it gives me the following warnings:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblibjasper.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/liblibjasper.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblibjpeg.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/liblibjpeg.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblibpng.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/liblibpng.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/liblibtiff.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/liblibtiff.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libzlib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libzlib.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libIlmImf.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libIlmImf.a
```

It seems to me that the application program is trying to invoke the dynamic opencv library, and a simple application program that just invokes `cv::Mat` test will give me the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in main.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in main.o
```

**EDIT:**
As the answers suggest it is not the link problem rather it is a problem of linking libraries built for different architecture. Besides that, two other important things you should pay attention to when building and using a static OpenCV library are:

1. Make sure it builds Active Architecture Only (yes).
2. Also you should link  `framework Cocoa;general;-framework QTKit;general;-framework QuartzCore;general;-framework AppKit;` that opencv_highgui.a uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that by passing no option to `cmake` command line it did build the libs for the native architecture of your machine (which is the default option), most presumably **x86_64**. However, for some reason, you're trying to build here a 32 bits **i386** application. Thus, you don't have the correct static libraries for your architecture.

You can solve it either by building OpenCV in 32 bits (`-Darch=i386`) in `cmake`) or by building your app 64 bits (native arch, or x86_64, depending on your build system).

If you feel brave, you can also build both 32 and 64 bits static libraries, assemble them into a universal binary, and link against that universal lib.

Comment: Thanks, but for both the application and the opencv library, I use 'My Mac 32'. By doing so, both will have the same architecture. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what 'My Mac 32' is... The only way to be sure of the arch that you build for is to explicitly set it in the compiler invocation, either by using cmake options or by adding something like CXXFLAGS = "-arch i386". By the way, unless you're building for some very old mac, it should be 64 bits by now.

Answer (score 2):

This is not about unsuccessful linking this is about unsuccessful building. '**file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)**'. You need to build it correctly, so to say, build it for correct architecture.

Comment: Thanks, but for both the application program and the opencv library, I use 'My Mac 32'. I think by doing so, both will have the same architecture.

Comment: Can you make it work when you build shared libs? If you can may be you should check out if there are any other changes happening when you change from static to shared. Maybe you can change `Host:                        Linux 3.2.0-51-generic x86_64` just to x86? And I don't know about linux but in windows when I extract the opencv package I have both shared and static libs build already, I don't need to build it myself unless I have to add QT_SUPPORT or any other thing.

Comment: @gunekayim Thanks, now I can compile it successfully. Please check the newly edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You should build your local application using:

```
cmake .. -DOpenCV_DIR=/path/to/opencv-3.0.0-beta/build/ -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64
```

ie. Force local build to be x86_64, which is what the opencv version is