# How can i use Opencv build in one Linux PC to the other?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I am trying to create a C++ application with opencv and share the application with other user who donot have Opencv installed on its PC. How can i do that?

I tried :

1. I copied all the header files, source files and libraries in some /home/myfolder path.

   2. I created the application and link all the files stored in /home/myfolder.
   3. set the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point /home/myfolder in .bashrc file so that application can find the libraries during run time.

I was able to compile on my PC, but when i share my folder with some other PC and link all the libraries, I get undefined reference error for Opencv.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming it's the same architecture and you just want to share the application itself, why not just pass the executable to the other PC and run? (of course you'll need to statically link the OpenCV libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both the PC are 64-bit. If i share only the executable it has to be linked with all the libraries like opencv, which is not in other PC. So i am setting environment variabel path in .bashrc to point the folder sharedand it has Opencv lib files, but still i am facing undefined reference error.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with static linking?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you mean to say after i built my application in my PC, I should copy the whole application with all the necessary header, source and lib files to the other PC and while compiling i should do static linking. Is my understanding correct?          How to do static linking? Please suggest.

Comment: Static linking means you integrate the required libraries into the executable itself. So it is truly a "standalone". This has the downside of increasing executable size.

Comment: my requirement is not only to give the executables but with all the source files and libraries. So that user can use my folder to build the application using the files i share and run the application.

Comment: That means you need to think about what happens when a) other user builds a new version, does your executable change? b) you patch your source, does that patch his? The answer may require you to use `git`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes that could be one point to take care

Answer (score 1):

The answer is static linking. If you don't care about executable size and the target machine doesn't have the required libraries, just supply them inside the executable.
Please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222248/building-opencv-as-static-libraries) question for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This answer has security implications - inform yourself before using and only use on a private network.

---

You could let the other user `ssh` into your PC and forward the X11 connection to his own machine using the `-X` or `-Y` options.

So, the other user would do:

```
ssh -Y someUser@yourPC yourApp
```

You will need to think about whether you want to trust that person to login as you, or whether you wanted to make a different user on your PC that could only run your specific app and no other.

---

Another option might be to let the other user make his X11 display available to your PC, by him typing the following on his machine:

```
xhost +
```

Then, you could start your app on your machine, but with the display forwarded to his machine - that way he doesn't need to log in to your machine or have your password:

```
DISPLAY=<otherPC>:0  yourApp
```